# SonarQube LDAP configuration & empty bindDN

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

My predecessor installed LDAP plug-in for SonarQube and added below configuration in sonar.properties file.

```
sonar.security.realm: LDAP
sonar.authenticator.createUsers: true
ldap.url: ldap://ldap.company.com:<port>
ldap.user.baseDn: DC=company,DC=com
ldap.bindDn:
ldap.bindPassword:
ldap.user.request: (&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=gpnet,OU=Groups,DC=company,DC=com)(SAMAccountName={0}))
```

He conifgured empty bindDN/bindPassword and when i looked at LDAP documentation in SonarQube under general configuration, it says

"Leave this blank for **anonymous access**  to the LDAP directory."

What it means? 
Any user who is part of ldap.url will be able to login? but as he/she is not part of gpnet group, so will not be able to login ?

As per my understanding, we should have service account credentials and set it in bindDN and bindPassword configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on other things in the configuration. It's possible to configure OpenLDAP to allow searches from an anonymous bind, which fits the usual pattern of searching for the use by some criterion such as email address, then attempting to bind as that user with his password as the actual login step.